# PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements. i am using oracle datadase 12c

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RDBSTAGE.ATCHMNT_ERR_FILEID AUTHID CURRENT_USER
IS
  CURSOR cv_atchtab IS
    SELECT * FROM ATTACHMENT_ERROR;

  type ATCHMNT_ERR_nt is table of cv_atchtab%ROWTYPE;
  I_ATCHMNT_ERR ATCHMNT_ERR_nt;

  type file_id_nt is table of VARCHAR2(40);
  V_FILE_ID file_id_nt;
BEGIN
  OPEN cv_atchtab;
  LOOP
    FETCH cv_atchtab BULK COLLECT INTO I_ATCHMNT_ERR;
    EXIT WHEN I_ATCHMNT_ERR.COUNT = 0; -- changed this

    FOR i IN 1..I_ATCHMNT_ERR.COUNT
    LOOP
      SELECT FILE_ID BULK COLLECT
      INTO V_FILE_ID
      FROM ATTACHMENT_CLAIM t1
      WHERE t1.CLAIM_TCN_ID = I_ATCHMNT_ERR(i).CLAIM_TCN_ID;

      UPDATE ATTACHMENT_ERROR t2
      SET FILE_ID = V_FILE_ID
      WHERE t2.CLAIM_TCN_ID = I_ATCHMNT_ERR(i).CLAIM_TCN_ID;  -- changed this
    END LOOP;

  END LOOP;    
  CLOSE cv_atchtab; 

END ATCHMNT_ERR_FILEID; 
/
Show ERRORS
```

Comment: I am getting PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
error while running above code

Comment: Can you please provide more context to your question? Something like what you've tried to solve the problem, or what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: In attachment_error table have many records.i have add one new file_id column  in attachment_error table .and need to update file_id column from attachment_claim table  where attachment_claim.claim_tcn_id=attachment_error.claim_tcn_id. In attachment_claim table already have file_id field.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm missing something, but - reading your comment, it looks like a simple `UPDATE` statement. Why would you do it in such a complicated way?

```
update attachment_error a set
  a.file_id = (select c.file_id
               from attachment_claim c
               where c.claim_tcn_id = a.claim_tcn_id;
```